# Update the document by separating array into objects using the string as first object in any array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I have a document like below

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5d0768f50557b958f0c6c9cf"),
     "list" : [ 
        "abc", 
        "xyz", 
        "mno"
     ],
  "timestamp" : "2019-06-17T10:18:29.986Z"
}
```

I need to update it like this below

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d07711dbf557c3d1878ff97"),
"list" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "abc",
        "type" : "car",
        "color" : "red"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "xyz",
        "type" : "bike",
        "color" : "black"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "mno",
        "type" : "auto",
        "color" : "blue"
    }
 ],
  "timestamp" : "2019-06-17T10:53:17.537Z"
}
```

Here I need to add two more fields i.e., "type" & "color" including "name" as shown in above code.

Is it good to use MongoDB aggregation as I need to deal with array and objects.

Comment: You need to supply two new properties for each existing item, so no, I don't think aggregation is a good choice here. Fetch the document into the app, transform it as you wish, and overwrite DB's copy.

Comment: any example would be helpful.

Comment: Example of what, how to read a document and write a document? Official documentation has those.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation is not the answer here, when you need to update your data you need use [update methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/update-methods/)

For example for your case:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   {_id: ObjectId("5d07711dbf557c3d1878ff97")},
   {
     $set: {
        time_stamp: Date.now()
     },
     $push: { 
        list:  {$each: 
      [{
        "name" : "xyz",
        "type" : "bike",
        "color" : "black"
       }, 
       {
        "name" : "mno",
        "type" : "auto",
        "color" : "blue"
        }]},
     }
   }
)
```